# display math formulas typed in Latex or asciiMath

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

I want to convert a user input written in Latex or AsciiMath to math formulausing  using MathJax with react. I have trouble implementing it especially that the input will be up to the user. Does anyone has an idea on how to begin?

Comment: You might take a look at this component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax4?activeTab=readme

Comment: There is also https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-react which works with MathJax v3 instead of v2.

Comment: this editor I made could serve a a sample. It takes the whole page as input though. https://jsfiddle.net/juanmf/Lz7nycxm/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax). It is a highly configurable package for using MathJax in React and the documentation contains examples of both static and dynamic content in Latex, AsciiMath and MathML.

Sandbox with dynamic example in Latex: https://codesandbox.io/s/better-react-mathjax-example-latex-3vsr5

Sandbox with dynamic example in AsciiMath: https://codesandbox.io/s/better-react-mathjax-example-asciimath-p0uf1

Just store the user input in a state variable and perform any validation and post-processing on it (to make sure that it is valid Latex or AsciiMath) and then use it in an expression like shown in one of the examples in the sandboxes.

PS. I wrote this package DS